# How can I move a 3D box in order to stay on a rotating plane?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, coordinate-transformation

I have a rotating plane and a box on it. When the plane rotates and tilts at an angle, I want the box to stay on the same position on the plane.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOouF.jpg) the plane is not tilted,

[image]

while  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOrkv.jpg) the plane is tilted,

[image]

but the box does not follow the plane downwards.

At every update I render the box, and translate it by the given `vec3` in `glm::translate`:

```
{
    glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1);
    modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(boxOX, boxOY, boxOZ));
    modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, RADIANS(anglePlaneOX), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
    modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, RADIANS(anglePlaneOY), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, RADIANS(anglePlaneOZ), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(0.2f));
    RenderSimpleMesh(meshes["box"], shaders["ShaderLab8"], modelMatrix, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
}
```

The plane moves by hitting WASD keys:

```
    if (window->KeyHold(GLFW_KEY_W) && (anglePlaneOX > -90.0f)) {
        anglePlaneOX -= deltaTime * DELTA_SLOPE;
    }
    if (window->KeyHold(GLFW_KEY_S) && (anglePlaneOX < 90.0f)) {
        anglePlaneOX += deltaTime * DELTA_SLOPE;
    }
    if (window->KeyHold(GLFW_KEY_D) && (anglePlaneOZ > -90.0f)) {
        anglePlaneOZ -= deltaTime * DELTA_SLOPE;
    }
    if (window->KeyHold(GLFW_KEY_A) && (anglePlaneOZ < 90.0f)) {
        anglePlaneOZ += deltaTime * DELTA_SLOPE;
    }
```

I tried the following

when pressing the A key:

```
boxOY += deltaTime * (1 - (float)cos((double)anglePlaneOZ * PI / 180));
```

when pressing the W key:

```
boxOX -= deltaTime * sinf(anglePlaneOX * PI / 180);
```

But none of those seem to work.

What are the mathematical relations in order to move the box accordingly to the plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the translation "before" the rotation:

```cpp
glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1);
```

<s>`modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(boxOX, boxOY, boxOZ));`</s>

```
modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, RADIANS(anglePlaneOX), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));  
modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, RADIANS(anglePlaneOY), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));  
modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, RADIANS(anglePlaneOZ), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));

modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(boxOX, boxOY, boxOZ)); //  translate here

modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(0.2f));
RenderSimpleMesh(meshes["box"], shaders["ShaderLab8"], modelMatrix, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
```

Explanation:

The translation matrix looks like this:

```cpp
glm::mat4 translate;
```

```
translate[0] : ( 1,  0,  0,  0 )
translate[1] : ( 0,  1,  0,  0 )
translate[2] : ( 0,  0,  1,  0 )
translate[3] : ( tx, ty, tz, 1 )
```

And the rotation matrix around Y-Axis looks like this:

```cpp
mat4  rotate;
float angle;
```

```
rotate[0] : ( cos(angle),  0, sin(angle), 0 )
rotate[1] : ( 0,           1, 0,          0 )
rotate[2] : ( -sin(angle), 0, cos(angle), 0 )
rotate[3] : ( 0,           0, 0,          1 )
```

The result of `translate * rotate` is this:

```
model[0] : ( cos(angle),  0,  sin(angle), 0 )
model[1] : ( 0,           1,  0,          0 )
model[2] : ( -sin(angle), 0,  cos(angle), 0 )
model[3] : ( tx,          ty, tz,         1 )
```

[image]

Note, the result of `rotate * translate` would be:

```
model[0] : ( cos(angle),                     0,   sin(angle),                     0 )
model[1] : ( 0,                              1,   0,                              0 )
model[2] : ( -sin(angle),                    0,   cos(angle),                     0 )
model[3] : ( cos(angle)*tx - sin(angle)*tx,  ty,  sin(angle)*tz + cos(angle)*tz,  1 )
```

[image]

Comment: This really helped, thank you. But the box seems to fall in the plane when the plane is tilted more than 45 degrees downwards (https://imgur.com/a/uydhjIy) and stays "above" the plane when tilted more than 45 degrees upwards. (https://imgur.com/a/3921x0U). The formulas used when pressing A key are:


   `boxOX -= deltaTime * (float)sinf(anglePlaneOZ * PI / 180);`


   `boxOY += deltaTime * (1 - (float)cos((double)anglePlaneOZ * PI / 180));`

Comment: The center of the cube mesh has to be in (0, 0, 0) and the position of the cube has to be completely defined by (`boxOX`, `boxOY`, `boxOZ`)

Comment: @DanBrezeanu Is the last parameter to RenderSimpleMesh the box position? Change that to 0,0,0, and use matrix translations to adjust the position.

Comment: @immibis  No, the last parameter is the color. The syntax is as follows `void RenderSimpleMesh(Mesh *mesh, Shader *shader, const glm::mat4 & modelMatrix, const glm::vec3 & color)`